# checkbox does not retain state in React

Tags: forms, checkbox, input, reactjs

when i click a checkbox in a tag panel, then it becomes checked as expect. But when i switch to another panel, and then switch back, i found that checkbox which should be checked turn to unchecked. how do i fix this?

here is my code, and i use `react-tab-panel` from npm.

`Container:`

```
export default class Container extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
    };
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            chosenItem: {
                a: [],
                b: [],
                c: [],
                d: []
            }
        };
    }

    handleCheckBoxChange = (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        const item = e.target.attributes.getNamedItem('data-tag').value;
        const chosenItem = this.state.chosenItem;
        const index = chosenItem[item].indexOf(value);
        if (index > -1) {
            chosenItem[item].splice(index, 1);

        }
        chosenItem[item].push(value);

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Panel
                    handleCheckBoxChange={this.handleCheckBoxChange}

                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

`Panel:`

```
import TabPanel from 'react-tab-panel';
import 'react-tab-panel/index.css';
import CheckBox from './CheckBox.jsx';

export default function Panel({

    handleCheckBoxChange
}) {
    const tabList = {
        a: ['1', '2'],
        b: ['1', '2'],
        c: ['1', '2'],
        d: ['1', '2']
    };

    return (
        <TabPanel
            tabPosition="left"
        >
        {
            Object.keys(tabList).map((key) => {
                return (
                    <form
                        key={key}
                        tabTitle={key}
                    >
                    {
                        tabList[key].map((item) =>
                            <CheckBox
                                key={item}
                                value={item}
                                handleCheckBoxChange={handleCheckBoxChange}
                                tag={key}
                            />
                        )
                    }
                    </form>
                );
            })
            }
        }
        </TabPanel>
    );
}
```

`Checkbox:`

```
export default function CheckBox({
    tag,
    value,

    handleCheckBoxChange
}) {
    return (
        <div>
            <label>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    value={value}

                    onChange={handleCheckBoxChange}
                    data-tag={tag}
                />
                {value}
            </label>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You should use [`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) to change the state of your component.

Comment: @robertklep setState is not a good solution in my case. because i also use react-router, so if i change path then back to this path, all state will gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html) or [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) for storing your application state tree.

Comment: i'm just using redux. and i already fixed it with redux. any way, thanks.

Comment: @Downpooooour Can you share how do you fix this?